# Entity/POJO with large number of attributes

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a Java application which maps some entities to tables using Hibernate.

One entity has gotten very large and contains maybe 30+ fields.

One suggestion is to add a map to this entity consisting of generic 'Attribute' objects which would replace some of the fields.

Would this be bad design and if so what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Tough it is not impossible, it is unusual to find entities with that many fields. I agree with @Gernot about giving a try to normalization.

Anyway, if you definitely need all of those attributes, go ahead and include them all. It is much better than the Map alternative you suggest, because it'd make your model lose *semantic* and *specific typing*.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if the database schema of the mapped table could be improved, if it contains that many fields. (have a look at [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization))

If this really is the case, a library like  [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) can at least reduce the amount of boilerplate to write (setters, getters, builder...).